# Git asks for password to push on WSL 2 (Ubuntu), but not on Windows. Why is that?

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I don't know why this is happening. When I try to push anything on Ubuntu (WSL 2) git keeps asking for my username and password, but when I push something through bash on Windows git doesn't ask for any credentials and I can push directly. I'm new to WS2L and Ubuntu so I don't know if this is normal or if something is wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-git#git-credential-manager-setup), you can link the Git Credential manager to WSL with

```
git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe"
```

As for the "why", it's because right now the git in your WSL and Windows use different credential stores.

Comment: I had to use >git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-wincred.exe"< today to make that work.

Comment: its not working for me anymore, any input please?

Comment: @lavoizer Things have changed since this answer was posted, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428365/does-anybody-know-how-to-get-github-ssh-to-work-correctly-on-wsl-windows-subsys