# I can´t clone my github repository with a ssh key

Tags: git, github, clone, ssh-keys, wsl-2

I can´t clone my github repository with a ssh key , the terminal said me -"git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
I'm using WSL2 along windows 10.

I just want to able cloning repositories of my github account with a ssh key.

Comment: Is this your repo? Are you trying to clone from your account a repo? Have you added your ssh key to your github account? You need to specify more details. Please complete the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Currently there are not enough information in your question to give you a answer.

Comment: Yes, Im trying to clone one project(repo) of my github github account , I added a ssh key to github account wich working because I can´t clone since the my terminal wsl2 but  I can do that since git bash wich is instaled in the windows 10 side, I copied the .ssh folder wich contains the ssh key of window 10 side (where git bash run and let me clone my repository of github correctly)but wsl2 keep show me the error message.

Comment: does this help: [sharing-ssh-keys-between-windows-and-wsl-2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/sharing-ssh-keys-between-windows-and-wsl-2/) [how-to-get-github-ssh-to-work-correctly-on-wsl-windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428365/how-to-get-github-ssh-to-work-correctly-on-wsl-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions on copied .ssh folder and (most of all) the private key inside that folder. You should `chmod 600` the private key and also `chmod 700` the .ssh folder. SSH requires you to protect your private keys.
Usually when you copy a folder or file from windows to wsl2 (starting from wsl2) it assigns by default 777 permissions.

Comment: this answer helped to me, the right solution was setting the file(private key) and folder(.ssh) permissions using the "chmod" command with (600 and 700 numbers respectively) and I see important add something related to the link suggested before by "topsail" wich its suggested write : "Execute the following command to copy the keys from Windows to WSL----->with the following command:
cp -r /mnt/c/Users/<username>/.ssh ~/.ssh"  , and my case its created one ".ssh" folder inside the "~/.ssh" folder, detail to watch to those one beggining to the time to fix the permissions .